# how to avoid showing selected option in next input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two input fields(input field 1 & input field 2) which have autofill options.if i select one of the options in input field 1 then that selected option should not show in the options of input field 2. how can i do that?

```
input field 1
<input type="text" ng-model="type1"  uib-typeahead="value for value in gettype($viewValue)" >

 input field 2
 <input type="text" ng-model="type2"  uib-typeahead="value for value in gettype($viewValue)">

$scope.gettype = function(val) {
return $http.get('api', {
  params: {
    type: val,
    sensor: false
  }
}).then(function(response){
  return response.data.type;
});
};
```

this is just a sample code what im planning to do is to create a ng-repeat which repeats the input field as much as i wanted

Comment: You could try by using the [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete) attribute on your 2 fields.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini thx for quick response. im using ui.bootstrap.typeahead

Comment: @Aswincj as other users already asked, it would more easy for you to find help if you would provide us a code sample where you have the issue.

Comment: Create a `filter` that takes model `type1` and apply it to `value for value in gettype($viewValue) | filtername`

Comment: @The_ehT thx. for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-blur option

considering autofille_data as your data

we can call a function on ng-blur

```
$scope.remode(autofill_data){
var index=autofill_data.indexOf($scope.input_val1);
 autofill_data.splice(index, 1);
}
```

where $scope.input_val1 is the value in input field 1

Answer (score 0):

repeat for creating text box.
    after that from array you need to remove those values which has been selected. for example:

```
html code

<span"><input type="text" ng-model="x.name1"</span>
<span"><input type="text" ng-model="x.name2"</span>
<span"><input type="text" ng-model="x.name3"</span>

js code:
Suppose your suggestion values are coming from array named $scope.usStates.
now you have to remove compare both value inside x an $scope.usStates and remove the matching element from $scope.usStates. you can use index of particullar element and splice method for removing an element.
example:
$scope.usStates.splice(index, 1);

$scope.usStates = [
    { name: 'ALABAMA', abbreviation: 'AL'},
    { name: 'ALASKA', abbreviation: 'AK'},
    { name: 'AMERICAN SAMOA', abbreviation: 'AS'},
    { name: 'ARIZONA', abbreviation: 'AZ'},
    { name: 'ARKANSAS', abbreviation: 'AR'},
    { name: 'CALIFORNIA', abbreviation: 'CA'},
    { name: 'COLORADO', abbreviation: 'CO'},
    { name: 'CONNECTICUT', abbreviation: 'CT'},
    { name: 'DELAWARE', abbreviation: 'DE'},
    { name: 'DISTRICT OF COLUMBIA', abbreviation: 'DC'},
    { name: 'FEDERATED STATES OF MICRONESIA', abbreviation: 'FM'},
    { name: 'FLORIDA', abbreviation: 'FL'},
    { name: 'GEORGIA', abbreviation: 'GA'}]

Thanks.
```